# beginner question about why my argument wasn't updated

Tags: python, function, arguments

why did my function not take account of my String update?

```
my_string = "hello"
def I_dont_understant (my_string_in_fonction=my_string):
    print((my_string_in_fonction))
my_string= "bye"
I_dont_understant()
I_dont_understant(my_string)
```

OUTPUT:

hello
bye

Comment: Running your code works for me as expected. 'Hello' and 'bye' are printed on two different lines of the output. Are you use you are seeing it correctly? Or maybe your terminal display is not setup properly?

Comment: The value of `my_string` in `my_string_in_fonction=my_string` is evaluated once at the time when the function is defined, not each time you call the function. But the value of `my_string` variable itself can change, as you see when you pass it as an arg in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

it's important to remember that python reads codes line by line. First, you are creating a new variable: my_string on top. so python reads that and equals to 'hello'. then, you are creating a function with a parameter my_string, so because python is still in line 2, it takes my_string as 'hello', and you changed the value of my_string in memory, so the value of my_string changed in memory and now is 'bye'. however, my_string in the function still equals to 'hello', because you gave your my_string to the function with an old value, which was 'hello'.

then you are calling your function, so it prints 'hello'
then you are calling and giving a new value, which is still my_string in name, but the value of it is already changed. therefore, new value will go into your function, and it prints 'bye'.

hope it helps!)

Comment: Adding to this, you should generally only use 'constant' values as function arg defaults. For anything else you should get the current value via code within the body of the function, not via arg defaults.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting valid output lets analyze your code line by line

```
my_string = "hello"
def I_dont_understant (my_string_in_fonction=my_string): 
# default parameter's value has "hello", if no value is passed in the function call then by default hello value will be assigned
    print((my_string_in_fonction))
#assigning my_string variable to "bye"
my_string= "bye"
# in the below function call we are not passing any argument hence default value will be taken into consideration i.e., "hello"
I_dont_understant()
# here in the below function call we are explicitly calling the function using updated my_string which is "bye"
I_dont_understant(my_string)
```

output:

```
hello
bye
```